# Same view controller loads twice on click of button

Tags: ios, controller, segue

I want to show a controller as pop-up on click of a button. Suppose I have VC1 that has button, then on click of that the VC2 should load as a pop up. It is working to some extent. But I don't' know for what reason the VC2 is loading twice and the second time it loads it shows black background. Here is my code:

On click of button below function gets called in VC1,

```
VC2* childVC = [[VC2 alloc]init];
childVC.view.hidden = YES;
[self addChildViewController:childVC];
[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToVC2" sender:self];
```

In VC2 viewdidload,

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

How can I make VC2 appear as a pop up properly?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to segue and add the child view controller's view to the current view controller's view hierarchy. You should do one or the other. I would suggest the segue as that is a more apple approved approach. So change this:

```
VC2* childVC = [[VC2 alloc]init];
childVC.view.hidden = YES;
[self addChildViewController:childVC];
[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToVC2" sender:self];
```

to

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToVC2" sender:self];
```